# how to compute rating score based on votes

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, economics

What is the formula to compute the rating score based on votes. Imagine each person can vote between 1 to 10. Now I have 20 votes from people. the results look like this:

```
[1 1 2 5 0 1 0 0 10 0]
```

Meaning that we have 1 vote for (1), 1 vote for (2), 2 votes for (3), ..., and 10 votes for 9, and 0 vote for (10). Now I want to compute a final score, like e.g. 8.75 (this is just a random score). Is there any formula to do that? The score should be something between 0 to 10. 
I think my post is kinda similar to this [Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942738/algorithm-to-calculate-rating-based-on-multiple-reviews-using-both-review-score). But i cannot understand how to use the formula there :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to find the average score.

$1\cdot1+2\cdot1+3\cdot2+4\cdot5+5\cdot0+6\cdot1+7\cdot0+8\cdot0+9\cdot10+10\cdot0=125
$

Then, divide it by the number of participants, $125/20=6.25$, which is the average score.